# Где обучиться python?

Tags: python

Подскажите, где можно получить неплохие знания в пайтоне. Книги, курсы и т.д.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно изучить основы языка, то [официальный туториал](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), но он только на английском.

Или книга [byte of python](https://wombat.org.ua/AByteOfPython/AByteofPythonRussian-2.02.pdf) на русском, начиная с пятой главы. Правда она не такая глубокая и во многом устарела.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитаты или документацию, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке] (/help/how-to-answer).